# How can I create a column of random numbers within set limits?

Tags: matlab, random

I need to create a 60x1 column that refers to a set of 10 images (1-10). Each image needs to be referred to 6 times, but in a randomised order. How can I create a randomised column that is within these limits? i.e. that references to image number 5 are randomly distributed but do not appear in the matrix more or less times than 6. I have read the matlab documentation on rand, randi, etc but I can't seem to see anything about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
result = repmat((1:10).', 6, 1);           %'// result in an "easy" order
result = result(randperm(numel(result)));  % // shuffle result to get random order
```